# SQlite - why do I need the commit command

Tags: python, sqlite

I use python (my IDE is pycharm) and new to SQlite. I read that I must use commit in order to save the data or changes, otherwise non of those would be saved to the table. I use a simple code to create a table in a database without using commit, define the headers and close the database file. Using DB_Browser I then open the file and see it is updated to what I have just made. Then my question is why do I need the commit command ?

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error


# Connecting SQLite to the Database
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    try:
        # Creates or opens a file called mydb with a SQLite3 DB
        db = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        # Get a cursor object
        cursor = db.cursor()
        # Check if table users does not exist and create it
        cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
                              users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, phone TEXT, email TEXT unique, password TEXT)''')
    except Error as e:
        # Roll back any change if something goes wrong
        db.rollback()
        raise e
    finally:
        # Close the db connection
        db.close()

fname = "mydb.db"
create_connection(fname)
```

Comment: I think you might be referring to git? There is a lot of intro material on git if you search on Google. I’d start there and if you have troubles then come back.

Comment: I believe you are talking about a database transaction: multiple sql statements that need to all execute successfully, or then roll them back. In this case, you are executing a single sql statement outside of a transaction, so no commit statement is necessary. [SQLite Transaction](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/)

Comment: Richard,
I found in your link "By default, SQLite is in auto-commit mode". That answers my questions. Very helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
commit()
```

This method commits the current transaction. If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html
Kindly go through the documentation you'll find answer 90% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, from [this](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-transaction/) link

By default, SQLite is in auto-commit mode.

Thanks to Richard for pointing this link.